# How to insert text in color

Tags: java, selenium, gmail

So i have this running test that need to send an email at the end.
This email sends using `Gmail` and all i want in some cases is to makred specific text in `Red`.

```
string body = "This is my red text"
```

In this case this is my email body that i am sending using `selenium`.
Is it possible to add attribute or something to this `string` and `Gmail` recognise  in `Red` instead of click on this option inside the email ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually despite what the others say it is definitely possible. It just is a bit of a hassle and you should decide for yourself if you want to do it this way.

You could achieve it by executing `Javascript`. The steps are:

1. Find the message element
2. Create a new `font` inside this element
3. Add a `color` to the created `font`
4. Add the text to the `font`

```java
public void addText(String text, String hexColor){
    WebElement element = // find the gmail textbox element here;
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    executor.executeScript(
        "font = arguments[0].appendChild(document.createElement('font'));" +
        "font.setAttribute('color', arguments[1]);" +
        "font.textContent = arguments[2];"
    , element, hexColor, text)
}
```

Comment: I would change the function slightly and call it addText(String text, String hexColor) and pass in the string to be colored and pass in a string representing the hex color. Now you can color text any color you want.

Comment: @JeffC Yea, I was thinking about that aswell but wanted to keep it simple for the answer. Guess I'll change it though.

Comment: Don't take my comment as a negative... you definitely answered the question. I just looked at it and saw an easy opportunity to make it more flexible.

Comment: @JeffC I didn't take it negative. I've changed the answer cause the you're right it's better that way :)

Comment: @RemcoW this works fine but when i pass the string i want to add (the body) i pass it with /n at the end of every line that i want and with this javascript the body it without any new line, any suggestion ?

Answer (score -3):

You can not change CSS using selenium. The easiest option will be to click option inside email.

Comment: Sure you can. Why do you say you can't? You can execute JS on the page using Selenium and with that you can do just about anything.